# Return min/max of multidimensional in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, max, min

I have a list in the form of

```
[ [[a,b,c],[d,e,f]] , [[a,b,c],[d,e,f]] , [[a,b,c],[d,e,f]] ... ] etc.
```

I want to return the minimal c value and the maximal c+f value. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, everything is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Tried min(list[0][2]) etc to try to get the maximal second index from each element's 0th cluster. No clue how to do the latter.

Comment: Charlie: No, just trying to put together a pet project. I'm an architecture graduate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the minimum `c`:

```
min(c for (a,b,c),(d,e,f) in your_list)
```

For the maximum `c+f`

```
max(c+f for (a,b,c),(d,e,f) in your_list)
```

Example:

```
>>> your_list = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]], [[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]]
>>> min(c for (a,b,c),(d,e,f) in lst)
2
>>> max(c+f for (a,b,c),(d,e,f) in lst)
11
```

Comment: This seems to work great; thank you! Didn't know you could do it this way (A for B in C format)

Comment: I like it.  I'm not sure list comprehensions are the best way to *explain* it to a beginning, but it's a lovely bit of code.

Comment: Oh, by the way, John, that's the magic term you want for this kind of code: "List comprehension".

Comment: @CharlieMartin: This is a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression), not a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-list_comprehension).

Answer (score 5):

[List comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to the rescue

```
a=[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], [[2,3,4],[4,5,6]]]
>>> min([x[0][2] for x in a])
3

>>> max([x[0][2]+ x[1][2] for x in a])
10
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to map your list to one containing just the items you care about.

Here is one possible way of doing this:

```
x = [[[5, 5, 3], [6, 9, 7]], [[6, 2, 4], [0, 7, 5]], [[2, 5, 6], [6, 6, 9]], [[7, 3, 5], [6, 3, 2]], [[3, 10, 1], [6, 8, 2]], [[1, 2, 2], [0, 9, 7]], [[9, 5, 2], [7, 9, 9]], [[4, 0, 0], [1, 10, 6]], [[1, 5, 6], [1, 7, 3]], [[6, 1, 4], [1, 2, 0]]]

minc = min(l[0][2] for l in x)
maxcf = max(l[0][2]+l[1][2] for l in x)
```

The contents of the `min` and `max` calls is what is called a ["generator"](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions), and is responsible for generating a mapping of the original data to the filtered data.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible.  You've got a list containing a list of two-element lists that turn out to be lists themselves.  Your basic algorithm is

```
for each of the pairs
    if c is less than minimum c so far
       make minimum c so far be c
    if (c+f) is greater than max c+f so far
       make max c+f so far be (c+f)
```

Answer (score 1):

suppose your list is stored in my_list:

```
min_c = min(e[0][2] for e in my_list)
max_c_plus_f = max(map(lambda e : e[0][2] + e[1][2], my_list))
```